# Got a "This item is not reviewable" during a suggested edit review

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I was redirected to [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1506621) on the suggested edit queue.

[image]

What was the purpose of this review for me? Is it the beginning of a honey pot for the suggest edit queue?

The user [doesn't have a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059007/saeid-a-k?tab=activity) for this question in his profil.

**Edit:**

It seems it was an audit, since a user just reviewed it. But I don't understand why it was in this state when I was redirected to it..

Comment: Another such review (doesn't look like an audit): http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1526391 ; Also, could it be related to the fact that I did a history-back/history-forward before seeing the review task?

Comment: @JanDvorak this was an audit :)

Comment: You're right; I was fooled by the edit time. Having seen how suggested edit audits are implemented (random changes, not old edits) - yeah, this was an audit.

Comment: By the way, how should we reject obvious audits? Invalid edit, or radical change?

Comment: So, "not reviewable" is an audit someone else is currently facing

Comment: @JanDvorak It seems so. To reject an *abvious audit*, just don't approve it (I think the system doesn't care about the reason).

Comment: I just faced this, too.